# Diagnosing alternator or starter on a 16 Chevy Cruze LT

Tags: battery, chevrolet, alternator, starter, cruze

how do you know if it's the battery starter or alternator in a 2016 chevy cruze lt when i started the car it sounded like it wasn't going to start also not sure if it's related but i had to get a jump twice last week and the next day when i turned it on all the lights were flashing and the wipers came on, what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Use a volt meter to check the battery voltage when the engine is running and again when it is stopped.

If the voltage is 13v or above when the engine is running, then the alternator is working fine.

If the alternator appears to be working and the voltage is below 12v when the engine is stopped then your battery is likely dying.

The easiest way to test the starter would be to put a known good fully charged battery on the car and see if the starter turns the engine well.

Test the battery voltages and report back.

Comment: Agree with what you've said here, was writing pretty much the same but got distracted. From the OPs description, I'd suggest the battery isn't charged correctly. My wife's car did pretty much exactly the same thing when the battery gave up the ghost. Anyway, spot on.